# Issue - My React Native App showing FirebaseError: Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently receiving the below error when attempting to use firebase cloud messaging in my react native app by calling firebase.messaging():

FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).

I am not too sure why I am getting the browser error as I am trying to use iOS push notification not web notification. I am not sure if I have setup firebase cloud messaging in my firebase console or if I need to. I have had a look at a few links but they haven't been helpful.

I am using a real iOS device when attempting to message on my app.

**Below is my firebase config:**

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCjWwL5rs6n-lTlqAkaEh5eK**********",
  authDomain: "appname***-36a**.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://appname***-36a**.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "appname***-36a**",
  storageBucket: "appname***-36a**.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "898189283****",
  appId: "1:898189283761:web:9e09a6566fcb0629d*****",
  measurementId: "G-VYF6PH0M**"
};



export default firebase;
```

I would like to eventually get the FCM registration token. Can someone please assist? I am using bare react native.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use messaging from this library.

**"@react-native-firebase/messaging"**

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
```

For more reference here is the official doc https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Comment: Thanks but installing "@react-native-firebase/messaging" gives me the error 'Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth' when building

Comment: did you install pods?

Comment: Yes. I run the command 'npm i @react-native-firebase/messaging' then the command 'cd ios/ && pod install'

Comment: @react-native-firebase/app
use this library instead of this import firebase from 'firebase/app';

Comment: Ok so I get the error ' ERROR  FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).' when following the steps in the link https://rnfirebase.io/ to install @react-native-firebase/app.